# El "container" no me funciona como debería ser

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy empezando en el mundillo con html y es que me surge un problema desde el minuto uno y es que cuando quiero poner una imagen y a continuación unos botones, los botones se van bajo la imagen y se ponen un poco por encima de ésta. No sé si es que no estoy usando bien el sistema de rejillas de bootstrap pero no sé cómo hacer para no tener este problema.
a continuación dejo el código y una imagen de lo que me sucede:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">                
            <!-- Logo de la página -->
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="./inicio.html">
                        <img id="logo" src="./img/wolf.png"/>
                    </a>
                </div>                

            <!-- Menú superior -->
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 1</a>
                    <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 2</a>
                    <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 3</a>
                    <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 4</a>
                    <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 5</a>
                    <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 6</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: ¿Y dónde quieres que aparezcan los botones?

Comment: Pues querría que aparecieran al lado de la imagen y no justo debajo

Comment: No entiendo mucho de `bootstrap` , pero tienes que jugar con las clases ([documento](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/)). En lugar de utilizar `class="col-md-3"` y `class="col-md-9"`, creo que lo más adecuado es poner `class="col-md-1"` en las dos.

Comment: Acabo de poner cada botón en una columna supuestamente en la misma fila y lo único que ha hecho es ponerse cada botón justamente debajo del anterior. A cada botón le he metido en un class="col-md-1"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La explicación para lo que te sucede es sencilla. No estás cargando correctamente **Bootstrap**.

Asegúrate de que en tu código hagas referencia a la ruta donde se encuentra, tanto para su `.css` como para su `.js`. Ten en cuenta también que la carga de la librería depende de **Jquery** por lo que deberá ser esta cargada antes que la de **Boostrap**.

En mi ejemplo se muestra el orden de carga correcto para que lo tengas presente, además de verse como usando tu **HTML** las clases de **Boostrap** están entrando en acción.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                
    <!-- Logo de la página -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="./inicio.html">
                <img id="logo" src="./img/wolf.png"/>
            </a>
        </div>                

    <!-- Menú superior -->
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 1</a>
            <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 2</a>
            <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 3</a>
            <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 4</a>
            <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 5</a>
            <a class="boton" href="./inicio.html">Boton 6</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eso es, estaba añadiendo dos `href`en un solo `<link>` y por eso no me cargaba. Muchísimas gracias, queda anotado

Comment: Me queda una duda, MyGuel: ¿Qué te da a entender que el OP no está cargando correctamente las librerías si no las muestra en su código?

Comment: @JheymanMejia La imagen que adjunta con su pregunta muestra que los elementos `.col` que tiene dentro del `.row` no se están colocando en la misma línea, como debería ocurrir si se estuviesen aplicando los **CSS** pertinentes. Al igual que tampoco se le están aplicando las medidas que otorga la clase `container`, apreciable en que sus elementos se están colocando pegados al extremo izquierdo en vez de verse más separados de este, como ocurre en mi *snniped*.

Comment: Muy buena esa observación!

Comment: Me sirvio genial, gracias